# Difference in rendering between staging and production on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a staging and production server on heroku. Both are running on Cedar 14 stack with the same database. Both have the same git commit deployed to it, and in general run exactly the same. However in Firefox, a select box renders slightly differently on staging and production. I am displaying staging and production in different tabs in the same firefox window. If I inspect the element using developer tools, the scss appears to be identical.

The screen shot of the staging and development version is

[image]

and the production version looks like this:

[image]

You can see that on production the "One Month' is partially obscured.

Most of the styling is simple_form and bootstrap, the only relevant of my own scss is

```
select#graph_line_duration{
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

This scss code can be seen by inspecting the element using web developer tools and it is active i.e. if I disable the font-size, then the view changes appropriately.

What can cause this and as an interim step, how do I confirm that my staging and production environments on heroku are exactly the same?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the difference?

Comment: I have posted screenshots of the difference.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: I am not seeing any errors in the console.